# How to make a checkbox disabled without using any specific condition?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a checkbox whose value is handled from the DB on the basis of the column isAllow. We have 5 names and corresponding to these name we have diff isAllow property. If the value of isAllow is true then the checkbox get checked.

For four names, I have to make the checkbox as checked, but for one specific name out of 5, I have to mark the checkbox as disabled as well. I can achieve this by adding a condition as:

```
if(name=="Josh" && isAllow)
{
  chkBrand.Enable=false;
  chkBrand.Checked=true;
}
```

I dont want to use the above condition here. I just want to get the checkbox as disable for a specific name without the condition.

Below is the code that I have used:

```
        bool isAllow = false;
        bool SigCard = false;

        List<AOTLuAffinity> oAotluAffinity = bsAffinity.DataSource as List<AOTLuAffinity>;

        foreach (AOTLuAffinity oAffinity in oAotluAffinity)
        {
            if (oAffinity.Name == comboName.SelectedValue.ToString())
            {

                isAllow = oAffinity.isAllowName;
                signCard = AOTHelper.GetHasSigCardValue(workflowid, Acct.AffinityNum, comboPaBranch.SelectedValue.ToString(), Applicants.AffinityNum, isSignCard, isAllow );
                if (isAllow)
                {                        
            chkBrand.Checked=true;// here for a specific name, I want to make the checkbox as disabled, but I dont want to use the condition.
                }
                else
                {
                    chkBrand.Checked=false;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

I am finding a hard time in getting this. Any help will be great.

Comment: What's so special about the one disabled name? How do you know to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Loop on the items you got from database and each time read value (isAllow),then

```
 chkBrand.Checked=isAllow;
```

Comment: chkBrand.Checked = isAllow; will be shorter

Answer (score 0):

I think the right approach here is to add a new field to the database, `isDisabled`, and then in your loop evaluate that field:

```
...

else
{
    chkBrand.Checked=false;
}

if (oAffinity.isDisabled)
{
    chkBrand.Enabled = false;
}

break;
```

Comment: having a new field to the database only for making the checkbox as disable will not be good I guess. I am getting 5 values of Name for isAllow as true, and I only want to make the checkbox as disabled for only one name.

Comment: @Yash, if you want to do it without the `if` statement, you're going to have to add it to the configuration. That was the question you asked. There is **clearly** no other way. If you don't read it from configuration, you're **clearly** left with a static condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ conditions to check specific names on a list. You must declare a list like this:

```
List<Person> peopleList = new List<Person>();
```

And here is your condition code:

```
        foreach (AOTLuAffinity oAffinity in oAotluAffinity)
        {
            if (oAffinity.Name == comboName.SelectedValue.ToString())
            {
                isAllow = oAffinity.isAllowName;
                signCard = AOTHelper.GetHasSigCardValue(workflowid, Acct.AffinityNum, comboPaBranch.SelectedValue.ToString(), Applicants.AffinityNum, isSignCard, isAllow );

                chkBrand.Checked = 
                                   peopleList
                                   .Count(c => c.Name ==  comboName.SelectedValue.ToString()) > 0 ? true : false;

                break;
            }
        }
```